# Windows Registry transaction log - is it always used?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I've read [here](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/deeper-windows-registry.htm), [here](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2019/01/digging-up-the-past-windows-registry-forensics-revisited.html) and elsewhere that Windows can use a transaction log when writing to the Windows Registry, and this can be used for forensics.

I'm aware of `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` and WMI, but I'm curious if the transaction log could also provide an alternative means for real-time monitoring of Registry changes.

My question, is the transaction log *always* used? The articles I've found tend to say thing like it "can" use it, but not if it *has* to.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction log is not always used, a conclusion based on the following data.

On my computer, these are the `*.dat.log*` files in `C:\Windows`:

[image]

You can see that the only file that was updated today was
`migration.dat` (which doesn't seem like being a registry hive).

Given that some registry hives are updated continuously, it seems that there is
no systematic logging being done on my computer. Hence my above conclusion.